# Uber API /v1.2/products endpoint timeout

Tags: uber-api

We hit Uber api often, and we are seeing in the last few days a high number of timeout responses. In particular for the `/v1.2/products` endpoint. This is happening to us since Fri Sep 14. Is there any issue with `https://api.uber.com/`? Any quota limit? Anyone else experiencing the same?

EDIT

Did more tests:

GET `https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=37.775978&longitude=-122.41823` **works ok**

GET `https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=40.72559&longitude=-112.07068` -> **got read timeout**

Looks like it depends on the city / location

Comment: Hello-- replied on the Developer forum about this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/uber-developers/o0XizrLE-0k

Products are set up by local city teams and they can occasionally cause issues with the API. Working to get this fixed, thx!